# cancel/disable window.location in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I link every row in my table with js

```html
<tr class="clickable-row" data-row-id="{{$Offer->offer_nr}}" data-href='link'>
```

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```

In my last cell, in every row, I have a button to open a modal. How can I cancel the window.location in JavaScript when I click the button to open my modal?

I made the last cell in my row unclickable with CSS:
`pointer-events: none;`
but the button is then also unclickable

I tried also to stop the window.location when I click on the button with

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete-record', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: You can look at what element triggered the click event and filter the process on that to ignore the window.location if it was the last cell that fired.

Comment: Can you provide an minimal runnable example?

Comment: The problem with the e.preventDefault code is that you’re running it inside a delegated listener set on the document.  This would trigger *after* the click on the TR so it’s not helpful in preventing that click.

Comment: @James Not sure about that, jQuery does weird things with ordering delegated events IIRC

Comment: In my comment I mixed up preventDefault and stopPropagation.  With the code changed to use stopPropagation the point is still valid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect if the button was clicked using the target of what was clicked.

```js
$(".clickable-row").click(function(e) {
  const deleteClicked = e.target.closest('.delete-record');
  if (deleteClicked) {
    // call delete modal if you want
    return false;
  } 
  // window.location = $(this).data("href");
  console.log($(this).data("href"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="a">
      <td>a</td>
      <td><button class="delete-record">X</button>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="b">
      <td>b</td>
      <td><button class="delete-record">X</button>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

or you can stop the event from going down the tree, but you can not use event delegation on the document because the event has already been fired on the row by the time it gets to the document. So you would need to bind to the buttons directly.

```js
$(".clickable-row").click(function(e) {
  // window.location = $(this).data("href");
  console.log("clicked row:", $(this).data("href"));
});

$(".delete-record").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("clicked button");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="a">
      <td>a</td>
      <td><button class="delete-record">X</button>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="b">
      <td>b</td>
      <td><button class="delete-record">X</button>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to prevent the default action (which is nothing for a click on a table cell), you want to [stop the event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) ([jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)):

```
$('.delete-record', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will cause your handler on `.clickable-row` to simply not trigger.

Comment: but the handler on .clickable-row trigger first, then the modal button triggers.

Comment: @CarloMeatman Don't use event delegation for the modal button (or use event delegation also for the `.clickable-row`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName == "BUTTON"){
    console.log("clicked button");
  }else{
    //window.location = "whatever";
    console.log("clicked row");
  }
    

});

$('table button').on('click', e => {
    console.log('button');

});
```

```css
td{padding:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td><button class="delete-record">click1</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td><button>click2</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>A3</td><td>B3</td><td><button>click3</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>A4</td><td>B4</td><td><button>click4</button></td></tr>

</table>
```